# Copy data from external program

Tags: excel, vba

I have a java window that we use to navigate customer information. We have to manually enter this information from the window into a pdf for printing.

I'm trying to use VBA just to select certain fields and copy them to a userform.

I've tried recording a mouse macro just to a worksheet and that didn't work.

I've tried this code...

```
Application.SendKeys("%{TAB}")
Application.SendKeys("^c")
text_box1.Value = FnGetTextFromClipboard()
```

the text from clipboard function does work perfectly so I know it's not that.
It will put whatever was in the clipboard into that textbox but it won't copy the value from the other window.

EDIT: I normally manually select the customer info and paste it into the pdf for printing. I'd like to automate it because the data in the java window is broken up quite a bit. First name, last name, phone # (in 3 fields), address (street, city, state, zip fields), etc.

I have no way to export the customer data to another format short of manually copying the information.

Comment: SendKeys based code will never be 100% reliable. Given that you've mentioned a pdf, if you have Word on your system, then it would be better to use a Word instance to parse the pdf file (assuming it recognises the fields as text, and not image), and extract the required fields

Comment: I would but I have no way other than manually selecting each field and copying it then pasting it from the java window. The data is split up alot. Even the phone number is area code in one field, the first 3 of the telephone number in another, and the last 4 in the final.

Comment: yes, I can auto populate the pdf once I have the data. Again, I have to either manually type it into a userform or worksheet or directly to the pdf or I have to highlight and copy it to paste it to the pdf/userform etc.  My roadblock is automating the data retrieval from the java program. I can get the rest of the process to work but if I have to manually move the data myself from the java program to something, then automation is pointless.

Comment: Pressing Tab to move to the next field doesn't necessarily select everything in that field, i.e. have you tried including `Application.SendKeys("^a")` _after_ your Tab, but _before_ your Copy ?

Comment: when you are in the java program, it does select everything, but it won't even send the tab, I did try it with ctrl a but that won't work either

Comment: Honestly, I think you should try a different toolkit, e.g. if you used `autohotkey`, then the [ControlGetText](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlGetText.htm) _might_ work for you (Excel can also be controlled from autohotkey).